# Add custom javascript directly on SharePoint installed pages (Application pages)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, application-pages

I know there are ways to add custom JavaScript to make changes in SharePoint installed pages like delegate controls, custom actions.
So, these all are using feature then deploying that feature to server.

I tried to add directly JavaScript in one of OOTB application page i.e. Upload.aspx but it is not executing.
Even tried to link external JavaScript file to directly on Upload.aspx using ScriptLink or Script tag too. But file is not loading to SharePoint page.

So, I am curious to know that it is not possible to directly add any type of JavaScript to SharePoint installed pages?
If yes, please help me how to do that.

**Note: I'm talking about to do thing manually without touching Visual Studio or Delegate control/Custom action approach.**

Comment: Just to clarify, you went into the 15 (or 12/14) hive, edited an application page in the layouts folder, and inserted some JavaScript there?

Comment: Exactly, did the same as you mentioned in your comment.